# Python .exe updating file text using __VERSION__

Tags: python

I'm going to turn my .py file into a single .exe using cmd to run `pyinstaller -w -F -i img.ico code.py`.
Once i send it out for download, I plan to update my variables through version updates. my goal is to click the button inside this file, search online if i have the latest version, and download it instantly into this name.exe. How is this typically done? Is it a hyperlink that pings a websites back end for a number? How do I host such a data from my website? This is how I think the code is structured. Lines 11 and 13 are missing. Any help is appreciated. :)

```
__VERSION__='0.9'
a=05.67
b=True
c="password"

from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
"""
def update():
    #### request online current __VERSION__ number
    if __VERSION__ > return:
        #### update this .exe's text file
        messagebox.showinfo("Program v1.0", "You have been updated to v1.0.")
        refresh()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Program v0.9", "You are on the latest version.")
"""
L=LabelFrame(root,bg='black',padx=100,pady=100)
L.pack()

B=Button(L,text='Check for update')#,command=update)
B.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems such an easy question, but it can be quite tricky to do safely.

On your website, put a file named e.g. `latest.txt`, that contains the version number of the latest version. It should probably also contain the size and a hash (e.g. SHA256) of the new program file.

Have your application read that file, e.g. using the `requests` module. If that version differs from the version in the current running example, it should download the new version.
Of course the latest version should *always* be available at a predictable url (e.g. `http://example.org/software/Program`).

The size and hash read earlier should be used to verify that the download is complete and intact.

Preferably, the new executable should be *encrypted*
using public key encryption *with authentication*. This is suprisingly hard to get right.
Encryption is done with your private key. Your program should contain the public key that can be used to *decrypt* the new program.

There could be one or more of the following problems;

- The user might be behind a firewall that blocks downloading executables. Encrypting the program should get around that.
- There might be a size or checksum mismatch after download. Discard the download.
- Decryption/authentication fails. Discard the download.
- The user could lack sufficient permission to write the program file to the correct location.

And of course: Someone could hack your server and put up a doctered program (malware) for download. Encrypting the program and making sure that the private key is *not* available on the server should help with that.

Comment: Very Impressive and thorough reply. This sounds like many hours of study. Do you know how the function would be written?

Comment: Downloading things with `requests` is easy; just follow the documentation. For public-key crypto; I'd say use `PyNCl`. That's also just a matter of following the documentation. For hashing use the built-in `hashlib`. The biggest potential probleem I see is not so much with the code but with overzealous firewalls.